# Detail in forge viewer vs A360

Tags: autodesk-forge

I made a query about this previously but with further investigation I still have a problem. The two screenshots show the same component in A360 and in our Forge viewer. The behaviour in A360 is what we want with only the external geometry of the component visible. This used to be the case in our webapp but a change made to the Forge viewer at some point means all the detail in the component is now visible, including internal details. How can we replicate the behaviour we see in A360 in our forge viewer?[A360](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGPxC.jpg)
[image: CADshare]

Comment: I think your second screenshot did not get uploaded. Can you try again so we can see the difference and check which one is the one you want to have your app display.

Comment: Hi Jaime, if you click the "A360" link in the text you'll see it....

Comment: Ah I see it ok, let me check with our viewer experts. I see that A360 is using Version 4.2, your viewer is probably using the latest. You could set that version as a temporally fix while we wait for the Viewer team to get back to me.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is to force The viewer at startup using

```
options.isAEC = false
```

This will make the Viewer go back to the Highlight view that A360 is using at the moment.

Comment: Great - we'll give it a try and get the issue closed. Thanks for the quick repsonse.